# Retrieve "TODO" lines from a text file

Tags: string, todo

I'm editing a project in GEdit (text editor). When I type `TODO` it highlights it yellow for future reference. I have quite a few of these `TODO`s around the place.

To make it clearer what I need to do, can anyone show me a way to extract any `TODO` lines from a bunch of files and put them into one text file called, for example, `TODOs.txt`?

I have something like this:

`// TODO: Error handling.`

And want it to be put in a file like this:

`* <file name> <line number> Error handling`

A Linux application (CLI, GUI don't mind) would be preferable, but a regex script or another method someone could come up with would be cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `grep TODO -rnf * > TODOs.txt`

Comment: I used `grep TODO -n * > TODOs.txt`. Thanks very much! I never knew it was that simple. Would you know of a way to remove any tabs or spaces preceding the `//` characters at the beginning of the TODO line?

Comment: In reply to the first comment, you could use `grep 'TODO.*' -rno * > TODOs.txt` to not include output from before it.

Answer (score 2):

**If the file is `git` version controlled**, you might want to reuse git's grep. To grep for TODOs in your source files you type the following command at the root of the repo

```
git grep TODO
```

The command outputs something like this:

```
[~/projects/atl][ros] > git grep TODO
atl_gazebo/src/plugins/quadrotor_gplugin.cpp:  // TODO: switch to attitude controller when in offboard mode
```

To include the line number add the `-n` flag:

```
[~/projects/atl][ros] > git grep -n TODO
atl_gazebo/src/plugins/quadrotor_gplugin.cpp:92:  // TODO: switch to attitude controller when in offboard mode
```

For more options docs are [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep).

Answer (score 1):

If your list of files which has TODO in them is stored in a file, say named "file_list.txt", run:

```
grep -n `cat file_list.txt` > TODOs.txt
```

This will retrieve a list of all the lines containing "TODO" string, prepended with filename and line #, and store that in TODOs.txt

Comment: BTW, if you want the exact format "* <file name> <line number> Error handling", that can easily be done as well but I assumed that the format was not important

Comment: nah the format given by `grep` is fine :-) I just needed the rough information.

Answer (score 1):

Riley Lark's (and EdoDodo's) answers are probably the most concise, however to not have the literal "TODO" text to show up in the output, you could use [ack](http://beyondgrep.com):

```
ack --no-group 'TODO (.*)' --output=' $1' > TODOs.txt
```

Output:

```
lib/Example.pm:102: Move _cmd out into a separate role
lib/Example.pm:364: Add a filename parameter
lib/Example2.pm:45: Move comment block to POD format
```

If you wanted some slightly different formatting then adding the `--no-group` option would provide:

```
lib/Example.pm
102: Move Move _cmd out into a separate role
364: Add a filename parameter

lib/Example2.pm
45: Move comment block to POD format
```

Answer (score 0):

This will recursively find any line with '// TODO' in any file under the current directory:

```
grep -rn '// *TODO' .
```

This cleans up the output a bit:

```
grep -rn '// *TODO' . | while read l; do
        echo "$(cut -d : -f 1,2 <<<"$l"):$(sed 's|.*//[[:space:]]*TODO||' <<<"$l")"
done
```

Note that this might break if there are colons (:) in your source code file names.

You can put the output in a file with a final redirection.

EDIT:

This is even better:

```
grep -rn '// *TODO' . | sed 's|^\([^:]*:[^:]*:\).*//[[:space:]]*TODO|\1|'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a command that will find all the TODOs in the directory you're in, and it's subdirectories, and put them in a text file:

```
grep 'TODO' -rn * > TODOs.txt
```

**EDIT:**

To remove the unnecessary output before it, you could use this command instead:

```
grep 'TODO.*' -rno * > TODOs.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Hade the same issue so came up with a simple python script to do it using git grep...

```
import os
import subprocess
from contextlib import suppress

result = subprocess.run("git grep -l TODO", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
lst = result.stdout.decode().split("\n")

with suppress(Exception): lst.remove(os.path.basename(__file__)) # remove this filename
with suppress(Exception): lst.remove("") # remove empty filename

todos = []
for file in lst:
    with open(file) as reader:
        for idx, row in enumerate(reader):
            if "TODO" in row: todos.append((file, idx, row))

for todo in todos:
    print(todo)
```