# Can I convert my TODO to a git bug?

Tags: java, git, github, bitbucket, todo

I am new to Git and did not find any reference for such a question. One un-answered post here at StackOverflow is [Similar Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223731/extract-todo-tags-from-source-code-and-convert-them-into-issues-on-bitbucket), also I found this [Possible similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186628/textbased-issue-tracker-todo-list-for-git) but I did not find an answer there as well..

I have some `//TODO <need to remember this>` remarks in my java program and I would have loved to convert them into a bug/task/issue using github/bitbucket.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why the down vote? did I do something wrong with this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271677/retrieve-todo-lines-from-a-text-file) extract all your //TODOs with grep:

```
grep TODO -rnf * > TODOs.txt
```

Then it should be possible to write a small script that reads this TODOs.txt file and makes use of [Github's api](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue) to create new issues:

```
POST /repos/:owner/:repo/issues

{
  "title": "Found a bug",
  "body": "I'm having a problem with this.",
  "assignee": "octocat",
  "milestone": 1,
  "labels": [
    "Label1",
    "Label2"
  ]
}
```

But this is left as an exercise ;)

Comment: Thanks it seems like this could solve my problem, cannot test it at the moment but still marking as answer!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/naholyr/github-todos seems pertinent.

> Github-Todos is a git hook to convert your TODOs into Github issues.